"CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
I am writing a small app to scan some documents, but i'm at the very beginning and i'm trying to test my backend by simply sending a small request from my frontend to check if they are properly connected. I am using docker compose for reactjs with npm, springboot and postgresql db. I run the docker compose and eveything works fine except for this error i get when i send the request from my frontend. CORS error image
I have followed the latest approach from springboot on cors: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/cors.html. It still doesnt work.
RestController:
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api")
public class DocumentsController {

@GetMapping("/test")
public String testEndpoint() {
    return "Dummy response from backend!";
}

@GetMapping("/")
public String homeEndpoint() {
    return "Welcome to the backend!";
}
}

WebSecurityConfig:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http

            .cors((cors) -> cors.
                    configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
            );

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
}

React.js Request:
const Home = () => {
const [response, setResponse] = useState('');

const sendTestRequest = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/test')
        .then((res) => {
            setResponse(res.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("There was an error making the request!", error);
        });
};

return (
    <div>
        <h1>Test Request</h1>
        <button onClick={sendTestRequest}>Send Request</button>
        {response && <p>Response from backend: {response}</p>}
    </div>
);
};

export default Home;

